# Filter an array of objects upon a value inside an array of objects inside in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I am fetching an array of objects as following :

```
const data =
  [ { id: 0, company: 'nike',   items: [{ id: 0, name: 'caret',        price: 100}] } 
  , { id: 1, company: 'adidas', items: [{ id: 1, name: 'mobile phone', price: 300}] } 
  ]
```

I want to filter that array of objects by checking the value of the property "name" inside the items array if it is "Caret" or not. If yes, I want to return the same array of objects with all its content but filtered. Which means, it will filter out the object whose item's name is not caret. How can I achieve this in javascript?!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: @Taplar Fixed now. Can you help pls?!

Comment: Alright, so what have you already tried?  What part is causing you problems?

Comment: @Taplar data.filter(i => i.items.map(item=> item.name === "Caret")

Comment: K, so instead of using `map()`, take a look at `includes()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: why are you ignoring my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for that ?

```js
const data =
  [{ id: 0, company: 'nike',   items: [{ id: 0, name: 'caret',        price: 100}]}
  ,{ id: 1, company: 'adidas', items: [{ id: 1, name: 'mobile phone', price: 300}]}
  ] 

const filterName = (arr, name)=>arr.filter(el=>el.items.some(x=>x.name==name))

onlyCaret = filterName(data,'caret')

console.log( onlyCaret[0].company )  // nike
console.log( onlyCaret )   // row 0 with  { ... company: 'nike' ..}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I suggest using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this scenario. `some` returns `true` or `false` if a match is found. `find` returns the found element.

Comment: @3limin4t0r correct, `array.some()` method is much smarter to use, thanks for that hint! (why didn't I think about it!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Array.filter and then loop through your items for a match

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const data = [
    {
        id:0,
        company: "nike"
            items:[
                  name: "caret",
                  price:100
            ]
    },
    {
        id:1,
        company: "adidas"
            items:[
                name: "mobile phone",
                price: 300
            ]
    },
    ]

const filteredCompanies = data.filter((company)=>{
    company.items.forEach((item)=>{
        if(item.name === "nike") return true
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yet, I want to return the same array without the targeted object filtered.

Comment: @Saif what you mean by same array?

Comment: do you mean the array of `data` or the array of `items`?

Comment: I mean the array of data. @JamesRushford

Comment: `return filteredCompanies` ?
or else, if you want it all intact, less the items that do not match, 
do 
`return data.map((company)=> { 
    company.items = company.items.filter((item)=> item.name === "carat")
    
   return company
 }`

Comment: @JamesRushford why company is involved?! I want to filter upon the name inside the items array!

Comment: The way Array.map works, is that is that is runs a function using each item in the array as the input for the function and replaces each value with what is returned. 
So, when we say `company` what we mean is each item in the array, i thought company might be the best name for these items.
In this case, we say we want to examine each item in the array that is `data`, we want to adjust the property called `items` to be a filtered list of `items` where we only want items that have a property called `name` that has a value of `"carat"`. then, we want to return the changed `company` to `data`

Comment: One-liner : `data.filter( company => !!company.items.find( item => item.name==="nike"))`

Comment: This answer does not work using `return true` inside an `forEach` callback will only return from the `forEach` callback, not from the `filter` callback.